# Why does the global jQuery object get overwritten after the page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

I'm writing a jQuery extension contained in a self executing function:

```
(function($) {
    // global variables for the purposes of this test
    __$ = $;
    __$support = $.support;

    $.support.abc = "123";

    // Setup for my extension goes here.

})(jQuery);
```

On my test page, I have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myplugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        console.log(__$ === $); // false
        console.log(__$support === $.support); // false
        console.log($.support.abc); // undefined
    });
</script>
```

Why does this happen? I have no other scripts or jQuery plugins that might overwrite the `jQuery` object.

I haven't been able to find what code in the jQuery source itself overwrites the `jQuery` object after the document is ready. Any ideas?

If there's no way to avoid this, what would be the correct procedure for defining new properties on the `jQuery.support` object that can still be accessed after the document is ready?

**EDIT:** I omitted a critical part of my test code that inadvertently reevaluated the jQuery source -- and explains why this issue was happening. See my answer below.

Comment: Are you certain your function is being executed?

Comment: @Matt, yes. The rest of the test page works, and everything in the plugin (which deals with the AJAX onprogress event) works correctly. But when I open the console and check `$.support.myproperty`, it's undefined, which is annoying because that means that users of my plugin can't take advantage of that check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I feel stupid.

My test code (the part that I hadn't posted in the question) was intentionally calling `jQuery.ajax()` on `jquery-1.5.2.js` (since this is a reasonably big file for testing progress events). However, I had forgotten that unless one manually sets the `dataType` option to something other than `script`, jQuery will evaluate any JavaScript that's retrieved by `jQuery.ajax()`.

So jQuery was evaluating a new copy of its own source code, and `window.jQuery` was therefore getting overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong because I get the [correct output](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/ZT8P2/).

Comment: If you look at the code generated by jsfiddle, they actually wrap your JavaScript code in `$(window).load(function() { /** your code **/})`, so it's not the same thing. I don't have time tonight, but I'll try to put up a standalone test page tomorrow.

Comment: @kpozin Oh yeah, forgot about that. I changed it, check it out. Same output.